# AWS Bitnami force http redirect to https

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, apache, bitnami

I'm trying to force the redirect to https on my wesbite, and added this into my `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf`

After i restart apache, it still doesnt redirect. Any ideas? Thanks

```
# Default Virtual Host configuration.

# Let Apache know we're behind a SSL reverse proxy
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs"
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://MYWEBSITE.com/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule /<none> / [L,R]
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
```

and in this file `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami-ssl.conf`, here is my code

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs"
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://MYWEBSITE.com/$1 [R,L]
  RewriteRule /<none> / [L,R]

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key"

  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
</VirtualHost>
```